# Cannot get into my Documents and Settings Folder

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

I tried going into Security - Advanced - Effective Permissions - Locations - Advanced - Find the User which in my case is Sony PC user and assign Full Control .. it accepts it and I still cannot
get in that folder ... also tried - Take Ownership  - No Luck ... Basicially I need to get in
so I can delete the IPhone update files .. so I can have disk space to UPDATE .. now it reads "Cannot update no disk space on your computer"  Help Help..

Kim

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more coherent?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered removing some junk off your 'Sony PC' onto external storage temporarily? If this isn't what the problem is please make it more obvious.

Usually if you can't gain access to files, they're probably in use or corrupt. Try restarting or closing some programs (grasping @ straws).

Answer (score 0):

This may be the result of file system corruption.  Click on "My Comnputer", and then right click on the hard drive with the files on.  Select "Properties", then click on the "Tools" tab.  Under "Error Checking" press "Check now".  Select "Automatically fix system errors" and "Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors".  When you press "Start" Windows will bring up a message saying it can't check now and ask you if you want to schedule a scan for the next reboot.  Select "Yes", and then reboot the computer.  This may fix your problem.